# graphene-mongo and nested json data

Tags: mongodb, graphql, mongoengine, graphene-python

i have the follow two documents in mongo:

```
> db.user.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("623d12f5ee5204c41f028944"), "uid" : "you", "uid_number" : 5678, "eppns" : [ "you@x.com", "y.com" ], "props" : { "one" : 1, "two" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("623d1310ee5204c41f028945"), "uid" : "me", "uid_number" : 123, "eppns" : [ "me@x.com", "me@y.com" ], "props" : { "one" : 3, "two" : 3 } }
```

defined with

```
from mongoengine import Document
from graphene_mongo import MongoengineObjectType
from mongoengine.fields import (
    FloatField,
    IntField,
    DictField,
    StringField,
    EmailField,
    ListField,
    URLField,
    ObjectIdField,
)
from graphene import ObjectType, Schema, List, Field
from graphene.relay import Node

class User(Document):
    meta = { 'collection': 'user' }
    ID = ObjectIdField()
    uid = StringField(required=True)
    uid_number = IntField(required=True)
    eppns = ListField( EmailField() )
    props = DictField()

class UserType(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class Query(ObjectType):
    node = Node.Field()
    users = List(UserType)

    def resolve_users(self, info, **kwargs):
        return User.objects.all()
```

yet, when i query as such:

```
{ users { id eppns uid uidNumber props } }
```

i get the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "623d12f5ee5204c41f028944",
        "eppns": [
          "you@x.com",
          "you@y.com"
        ],
        "uid": "you",
        "uidNumber": 5678,
        "props": "{\"one\": 1.0, \"two\": 2.0}"
      },
      {
        "id": "623d1310ee5204c41f028945",
        "eppns": [
          "me@x.com",
          "me@y.com"
        ],
        "uid": "me",
        "uidNumber": 123,
        "props": "{\"one\": 3.0, \"two\": 3.0}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

ie, it does not render `props` as json, but as a string. how can i get props to render/resolve as a dict? i would prefer not to define props as another Document and $ref it.

Answer (score 0):

getting the same problem and I found a possible [solution](https://medium.com/open-graphql/jsonfield-models-in-graphene-django-308ae43d14ee) with `graphene_django` and it solved my problem.

You just need to override your `props` field with `GenericScalar` in your `UserType`:

```
from graphene.types.generic import GenericScalar # solution

class UserType(MongoengineObjectType):
    props = GenericScalar()

    class Meta:
        model = User
```